# How to implement object collision on imported wavefront OBJ files in 3D

Tags: python, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm making a 3D maze Game in pyGame and made the environment in an OBJ file and used the OBJFileLoader found on the pyGame website to load it into my game. But when I implemented the movement controls the camera passes through the model. How do I detect collisions between my camera and the model so that I can fix that?

I thought about using rectangular collision detections but all the implementations I could find were in 2D and had a hard time trying to do it in 3D also using obj files didn't make it any easier. I also read somewhere that I can use raytracing but I couldn't find anything related to using raycasting in pyGame.

Below is the code I have in the main loop for controlling the in-game movement

```
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()

    time_passed = clock.tick()
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed / 1000.

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    rotation_direction.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    movement_direction.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    if pressed[K_a]:
        rotation_direction.y = +1.0
    elif pressed[K_d]:
        rotation_direction.y = -1.0
    if pressed[K_w]:
        movement_direction.z = -1.0
    elif pressed[K_s]:
        movement_direction.z = +1.0

    # Calculate rotation matrix and multiply by camera matrix
    rotation = rotation_direction * rotation_speed * time_passed_seconds
    rotation_matrix = Matrix44.xyz_rotation(*rotation)
    camera_matrix *= rotation_matrix

    # Calcluate movment and add it to camera matrix translate
    heading = Vector3(camera_matrix.forward)
    movement = heading * movement_direction.z * movement_speed
    camera_matrix.translate += movement * time_passed_seconds

    # Upload the inverse camera matrix to OpenGL
    glLoadMatrixd(camera_matrix.get_inverse().to_opengl())

    glCallList(obj.gl_list)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm very confused as to how I can actually block the user from moving through the walls and I need to do that for the maze game I'm making to actually work.

Comment: You might be able to make some simplifying assumptions depending on the layout of the maze. Is it essentially "2D" from a top-down perspective? Does it follow a grid? Is this in a first person perspective (in which case the camera could be treated as a point or bounding sphere) or third person (in which case you could make a simplifying mesh representing the boundaries of the object rather than testing the actual mesh itself triangle by triangle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking using a 3D geometry mesh as your collision detection data isn't a great idea. Usually the way we do this is to have a much simpler collision geometry *(ideally composed of simple primitives such as boxes, cylinders, spheres, planes - although tri meshes can be used in some cases)*. The player/camera is then usually represented as a capsule, and we test the capsule against the geometry. Implementing this form of collision detection in 3D is *REALLY* hard.

If it is possible to boil the maze game down to a 2D problem *(e.g. a top down view)*, then define a set of 2D lines that define the outline of the maze, and treat the player/camera as a circle.

Even the 2D scenario though is difficult. The best system would need to solve a load of simultaneous equations in order to determine the closest intersection. As the size of the maze increases, the complexity of solving this becomes extremely unpleasant *(i.e. you'd need to use some form of spatial partition, such as BSP tree, quad trees, etc)*

It is a very hard problem, which is why most sane people would simply make use of a physics engine to perform these calculations for them. I'd probably recommend trying to get your head around a simple 2D physics engine first, e.g. Box2D. If you absolutely need 3D collision detection, then you probably want to be looking at PhysX, bullet, or Havok.